# function file_exists not working in php

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to find if a file_exist in the directory. If not i want to use  a different image. But as i am using the file_exists function it always returns false.

The code i used is

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {  
        if(!file_exists('http://localhost/dropbox/lib/admin/'.$r[5]))
            {
                $file='http://localhost/dropbox/lib/admin/images/noimage.gif';
            }
        else
            $file='http://localhost/dropbox/lib/admin/'.$r[5];}
```

But the function always return false even if the file exits. I checked that by using

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://localhost/dropbox/lib/admin/'.$r[5]; ?>" />
```

This displayed the image correctly.

**Please Someone Help Me**

Comment: you use http addres, but should use like /var/www/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing URL to the file_exists function which is wrong. Instead of that pass your local path of the folder.

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{  
 if(!file_exists('/dropbox/lib/admin/'.$r[5]))
 {
  $file='/dropbox/lib/admin/images/noimage.gif';
 }
 else
 $file='/dropbox/lib/admin/'.$r[5];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`file_exists` uses *file system paths*, not URLs. You use URLs in a browser to access your PHP scripts through a web browser and web server over the network. The PHP script itself can access the local file system though and uses that, it does not go through the network stack to access files.

So use something like `file_exists('C:\\foo\\bar\\dropbox\\lib\\admin\\' ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` does not support addresses using HTTP (you can see this because `stat` is not included on [the list of wrappers supported over HTTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)). As the [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) documentation says, remote files can be checked with some wrappers, such as FTP, but it is not possible over HTTP, so `file_exists` will always return false.

Presuming that this file is on the local machine (which is suggested by `localhost`, you'll need to access it with a local file path. It's hard to guess what this might be for you, but it might look like `/var/www/dropbox...`.

Answer (score 0):

[`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) checks if file exists in local filesystem. You're passing an URL. Change it to local path to your dropbox directory and it should work:

```
if(file_exists('/path/to/your/dropbox'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `file_exists` can only work for URL protocols that are supported by the `stat()` function in PHP.

Currently, the `http` protocol is not supported by this wrapper.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

Answer (score 0):

You are passing URL to the file_exists function which is wrong parameter. Instead of that pass your local path there.

To know more about file_exist() function read this php manual :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php